# Snazzy maps - marker does not appear

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a problem with that marker does not appear.
Map's styles ok, everything is ok except marker...

Here is the html and javascript code...

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.431536, 4.380121);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14
        , center: myLatLng
        , disableDefaultUI: false
        , scrollwheel: true
        , navigationControl: true
        , mapTypeControl: false
        , scaleControl: true
        , draggable: true
        , mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'roadatlas']
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.431536, 4.380121)
        , animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        , icon: 'images/location_pin.png'
        , title: 'ASL'
    });

    var styledMapOptions = {
        name: 'US Road Atlas'
    };
    var usRoadMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(roadAtlasStyles, styledMapOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('roadatlas', usRoadMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('roadatlas');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);});
```

> Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `map` attribute in your marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.431536, 4.380121)
        , animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        , icon: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/location-24-128.png'
        , title: 'ASL'
        , map : map

    });
```

Also, you have a syntax error in this line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);});
```

Rewrite it to:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

JSFIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t9pgsv6g/

Comment: Thank you. Missing map attribute.